# Can I separate a list by keywords?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Say I have a list:

```
Something something apple
Something something orange
Something something banana
Something apple something
Something banana something
Something orange something
Something something apple pie
```

And I want to separate the list into separate columns/lists with certain keywords (e.g. apple, orange, banana) like so:

```
Something something apple
Something apple something
Something something apple pie

Something something orange
Something orange something

Something something banana
Something banana something
```

Can I do that in Excel?

Comment: I would use MS Access in this case, instead of Excel. Then, you could generate reports using a query, and do exactly what you are asking.

Comment: What should be done with a record like:  **banana something apple**

Comment: @Edward Thanks. Do you know of a simple tutorial?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Great question... I'm not quite sure. Perhaps a separate list with multiple keywords? It's not really a big deal though.

Comment: I don't know of a simple tutorial. I took integrated apps in college, so that's how I learned it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Add-In for this.  You can start a Query from an Excel Table.

I've built a working demo of this which you can get from my One Drive - it's called

Power Query demo - searching for a list of keywords

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=4FA287BBC10EC562%21398

Basically the steps were to split the input text into columns then unpivot them into a row for each word.  Then I used a Merge to join the list of search words.  To get the grouped presentation I added a Pivot Table.