# searching for a set of strings in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, search

I have set of terms and a set of strings that may or may not contain one or more of those terms. I'd like to search for if there is a match for one or more of the terms.

Search terms (cells `A1:A17` in the example below)

```
* bob  
* linda  
* sam
```

Search strings  (column `E` in the example below)

```
* I'm sam  
* I'm lucy  
* Please find sam or bob or lucy
```

Currently I'm using an `OR` function with a bunch of search functions nested. For example:
    `=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$2,E33)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$3,E33)),....,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$17,E33))),1,0)`

I'd prefer some way to use the equivalent of SQL's     substring IN (1,2,3,4)

Comment: Do you just need to flag if any one of them exists in the target cell or do you need to do anything else, like count them? Excel's FIND function is great for this kind of thing.

Comment: Available features vary by version. What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I"m working on Office 2011 (Mac)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you understand how to search for a word in a string:

```
SEARCH(A$2, E1)
```

searches for the value of `A2` (“bob”) in `E1` (which might be something like “I’m sam”). 
This returns `#VALUE`, since “bob” does not appear in “I’m sam”.  However,

```
SEARCH("sam", "I'm sam")
```

returns `5`, because “sam” appears in “I’m sam”, starting at the 5th character.

You’re asking for the trick to scale this to a large number of search strings. 
The trick is to use *array formulas*.  An array formula looks a little like this:

```
=SEARCH(A$2:A$17, E1)
```

which searches `E1` for *each* of the values in `A2:A17`, creating an array of 16 results. 
For the example data, these results look like { `#VALUE`; `#VALUE`; `5`; … }.

> See important note at the bottom of this answer.

You can’t use this by itself, because a cell needs to evaluate to a value, not an array. 
But you can do something like

```
=COUNT(SEARCH(A$2:A$17, E1))
```

which counts the numbers in the `SEARCH` result
– i.e., it tells *how many* of the `A` words (“bob”, “linda”, “sam”, etc.) were found in `E1`. 
So, your

```
=IF( OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$2,E1)),…,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A$17,E1))), 1, 0)
```

formula (`1` if at least one word was found, `0` otherwise) can be replaced with

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH(A$2:A$17, E1))>0, 1, 0)
```

or simply

```
=--(COUNT(SEARCH(A$2:A$17, $E1))>0)
```

(Putting `--` (double minus) in front of a `TRUE`/`FALSE` value turns it into `1` or `0`,
respectively.)

But you probably want to do more than just determine *whether* one of the strings matches;
you probably want to know *which* one.  Well, remember when I said that
`SEARCH(A$2:A$17, E1)` evaluated to the array { `#VALUE`; `#VALUE`; `5`; … }? 
Let’s extract the `5` from that:

```
 =MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH(A$2:A$17, $E1), ""))
```

- `ISERROR` is a little like `ISNUMBER` except the other way around;
  it returns `TRUE` if the parameter is an error value and `FALSE` if it’s a normal value
  (number, Boolean, date or string).
- `IFERROR` is a very convenient function;

  ```
  IFERROR(calculated_value, default_value)
  ```

  is short for

  ```
  IF(ISERROR(calculated_value), default_value, calculated_value)
  ```

  i.e., it substitutes a default value (typically a *non*-error value) for an error value.
- So `IFERROR(SEARCH(A$2:A$17, $E1), "")` changes the above array result to { `""`; `""`; `5`; … }.
- And then `MIN( the_above )` extracts the lowest number from the array,
  skipping the empty strings.  Normally this will be the *only* number,
  except in cases like “Please find sam or bob or lucy”, where there are multiple matches. 
  In these cases, it will be the first match in the `E` string (here, `13`, where “sam” appears).

So, now do

```
=MATCH(MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH(A$2:A$17, E1), "")), SEARCH(A$2:A$17,E1))
```

This (`MATCH`) looks for the `5` (or `13` or whatever) in the full search results
to see where it occurs.  In the above examples, this returns `3`,
because the `5` (or `13` or whatever) is the third element in the search result
– because it corresponds to “sam”, which is the third search word.

In the image below,

- `F1` (number of matches) = `=COUNT(SEARCH(A$2:A$17, E1))`
- `G1` (location of first match) = `=MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH(A$2:A$17, E1), FALSE))`
- `H1` (index (string number) of first match) =
              `=MATCH(MIN(IFERROR(SEARCH(A$2:A$17, E1), "")), SEARCH(A$2:A$17,E1))`

  [image]

#### Important notes:

- When you type an array formula (i.e., any of the formulas discussed above),
  enter it by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
  This will cause it to appear with curly braces around it.  Do not type the curly braces manually.
- The above formulas assume that your data to be searched (“I’m sam”, etc.) start in cell `E1`. 
  Adjust as necessary.  Enter the formulas corresponding to the first row of your data and drag down.
- Avoid blank cells in `A2:A17`, because `SEARCH` will find the empty string in every string.

Comment: This is wonderful and elegant..  I know about array formulas but I would not have thought to adjust the formula to use COUNT()>0.

Comment: thanks again.  I've been trying to modify this to count the number of rows in an array that fit the search formula but I'm missing something.
=COUNT(SEARCH(A$2:A$17,E$1:E$9)) and it just returns "1".
Given your sample data above, I'd expect "5".
Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: You’re trying to do too much at once. `=COUNT(SEARCH(A$2:A$17, E1))` does `SEARCH(A2, E1))`, `SEARCH(A3, E1))`, `SEARCH(A4, E1))`, …. But `=COUNT(SEARCH(A$2:A$17,E$1:E$9))` doesn’t count the results of the first `COUNT`; it does `SEARCH(A2, E1))`, `SEARCH(A3, E2))`, `SEARCH(A4, E3))`, …. Try something like `=COUNT(F$1:F$9, ">0")`.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a very similar question to this, and built a working demo using the Power Query Add-In.

Here's that previous question & answer:

[Can I separate a list by keywords?](https://superuser.com/questions/788652/can-i-separate-a-list-by-keywords)